# Print the value in next line once it reached 6th cell value in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to VBA.

I have an excel sheet,
`Sheet1` contains values `6 * 6` matrix with values
Variables in each cell

[image]

`Sheet2` contains Maximum Character length `6* 6` matrix of each values in `Sheet1`
Maximum Character length of each values in `sheet1`

[image]

I tried to create a notepad and print the values which is in Sheet1 and place the cursor based on the maximum character length.

For Example: In sheet1, Value "First Message" as 13 character so it compare the Sheet2 same row and column as Maximum character length(30) and print in notepad, it should have 17 character length should be empty in notepad. As the same it has to print the same next values in the notepad in the same line which has to start from 31st character. 
Finally at every 1st row 6th column, it has to go to newline and start from 1st character position.

Below is my piece of code, Kindly help me to print in the notepad.

```
Sub myself()

Dim str As String
Dim MaxStrLen As String
Dim rest As Integer
Dim Lstr As Integer
Dim LMstr As Integer
Dim MStr As Integer
Dim LR As Range
Dim CNT As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim h As Long

Dim FilePath As String

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")


Open "C:\Users\Antony\Desktop\test.txt" For Output As #2


h = 1

With ws1
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Do
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        For j = 1 To LastCol

            str = .Cells(i, j).Value
            MStr = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value

                Lstr = Len(str)

            rest = MStr - Lstr
            Set LR = .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, LastCol))
            'CNT = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count


 Print #2, str & Space(rest)
            If j = Lastcolumn Then
            Print #2, vbNewLine

                    Else: End If

            Next
        Next

    Loop While LR <= LastRow

End With


Close #2

End Sub
```

Really appreciate your effort in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this code has run ever.

No need for Do loop. BTW While condition is wrong as you compare a range with an int.

Print command prints entire line including crlf, so the line should be assembled in another way, like this:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
        sOut = vbNullString
        For j = 1 To LastCol
            str = .Cells(i, j).Value
            MStr = ws2.Cells(i, j).Value
            Lstr = Len(str)
            rest = MStr - Lstr
            sOut = sOut & str & Space(rest)
        Next
        Print #2, sOut
    Next
Next
```